# Is there a fairly complete current stable Ubuntu version Docker container? The Docker.hub one is very stripped down & doesn't have some basic commands

Tags: command-line, ssd, docker, raspberrypi, sd-card

Is there a fairly complete, current, stable version of Ubuntu in a Docker container? I'm running Docker under a 4GB Raspberry Pi 4b with 128GB sd card, soon to be a 256GB M.2 SSD. So I should have plenty of space for containers, swapfiles, etc. I don't need a desktop, but I would like some basic commands. For example, "ifconfig" was missing. Okay, so I can install the iputils package. But I don't know the names of all the other packages to make it a fairly functional system, and I don't want to spend hours trying to find and install a bunch of packages to make the system functional.

Is there an "official" Docker Ubuntu container with all the usual Linux/Ubuntu builtin command-line commands like top, etc?

Comment: If you were trying to use `ifconfig`, your own knowledge is very *outdated* (maybe look at this 2012 post - https://serverfault.com/questions/458628/should-i-quit-using-ifconfig) and so how *clear* is your other knowledge

Comment: Yes. I AM very old and my knowledge of Linux is old as well. I had my hands on an IBM 1620 computer with discrete core at my JCC, most likely waaaay before you were a gleam in your parents' eyes. However ifconfig does what I want it to do. Just listing the interfaces with some details. Anything beyond that and I'd find other, better tools to use. I was just illustration what I saw as a stripped down system and a lack of "standard" linux commands. I tried a few others where also weren't there. But thank you for the link. I'll check it out.

Comment: Nothing wrong with being *old*, and whilst I've never used (*possibly never seen a running IBM 1620*), my first program was created on cards, as getting access to time-share terminals was a 'privilege' we couldn't always achieve.  Technology moves on, so *deprecated* tools like `ifconfig` are still available for those of us that used it long ago, it's not a Linux default with only basic *modern* tools only will be included by default.

Comment: I have fond memories of IBM 026 and 029 keypunches and learning how to program them to make inputting Fortran programs easier. I still have a small reel of tape from a DEC PDP-8 that was used in the Electronics Lab at the U of Az. And a few boxes of punched cards that I never got around to throwing away. LOL. I remember using their  teletype machines that had paper tape. My background is mostly large IBM systems. I came into Linux very late, as a result of a job change and admit I have fairly limited knowledge. But I love using a Raspberry Pi in comparison to a multi-million dollar mainframe.

Answer (score 6):

> *The Docker.hub one is very stripped down & doesn't have some basic commands*

The premise here is wrong. You give *one example* of a deprecated command - and make the conclusion that Ubuntu is not up to date.

The official [Ubuntu images](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu) include all basic commands (including GNU coreutils) for a modern Linux system.

`ifconfig` is part of the `net-tools` package, which has been deprecated for years - but can be installed anyway.

[See here](https://iamhow.com/Technical_Notes/Replacement_commands_for_net-tools_cheatsheet.html) for the commands that have replaced the ancient `net-tools` package.

Also, please see [this meta answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/20179/1066942) for an explanation of core elements that have changed in Ubuntu (and also in part Linux in general) over time.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried a few other things that appeared to be missing to me. I didn't think it was not up to date. I merely thought it was a stipped down version of the latest Ubuntu so as to be container/Docker friendly. My bad. I'm definitely looking forwared to installing a very current, full featured version, without a desktop. Thanks for the links. I'll check them out. I can't believe someone downvoted my simple question since I haven't dealt with linux in a long time.

Comment: This explains a lot. Things do change, and some commands that were valid 10 years ago aren't anymore on Ubuntu. For instance, networking also has changed to Netplan.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a fairly complete, current, stable version of Ubuntu in a Docker container?

Maybe, but why?

Docker containers are meant to host a single service. The Ubuntu Docker Images are commonly a starting point for creating your own images. As part of creating images, you'd typically install dependencies in the docker image.

Furthermore, as they host a single service, you *really* don't want a complete image. You want a minimalist image with only the packages you need, and nothing else - both to reduce disk footprint, but also to minimize attack surface.

So in short - there's no reason why people want what you ask for. Yes, there *may be* edge cases where it's useful, but then roll your own image.

```yaml
FROM ubuntu:latest

LABEL Ubuntu image with ubuntu-desktop installed

RUN apt update && apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

Something like those three lines should be enough to build a custom Docker image based on Ubuntu:latest with Ubuntu-Desktop metapackage installed.

Place it in `Dockerfile` and run `docker build .` to build your own image.

Comment: Thank you. I'm brand new to Docker so I don't yet know how to create my own images so I appreciate that tip. I guess what I was thinking isn't practical. I thought I'd run Raspbian OS and then have a Docker container with a Ubuntu Desktop system for learning/comparing with Debian. I'll also look into BerryBoot as I'll have an SSD.

Comment: That's generally not intended use case for Docker. It's more for making deployment highly reproducible and scalable, and in general the principle is 1 service = 1 container, although this is not a *technical* limitation.

Comment: Great. Thanks. I'm understanding it more and more. One of my goals is to use Docker images for Home Assistant and OpenHAB. Plus thinks like using the Influx database and other utilities.

Comment: Then you should probably run [Homeassistant's Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/homeassistant/home-assistant), Influx and so forth. Each service, one image.

Comment: Okay great thanks.

Comment: @Artur Meinild. THANK YOU! THANK YOU! THANK YOU! That link to iamhow.com was incredible. It had the information you generously recommended about the deprecated Linux commands. However, it has a TON of other really useful information about Linux and others. Fantastic resource. Thank you!